# 'int' does not contain a definition and no extension method

Tags: c#

I am facing the below error

'int' does not contain a definition for 'LeaveType' and no extension method 'LeaveType' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

here is my code :

```
public DataSet GetLeaveRecord(int empID)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[p_GetLeaveRecord_LMS]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", empID.LeaveType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdEmployee", empID.EmployeeId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", empIDd.DateFrom);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo ", empID.DateTo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", empID.Reason);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: empID is type of int and next code: empID.LeaveType is incorrect? Isn't it?

Comment: @AmmarAsjad: You haven't given us enough information... but you need to **think** about the problem. You're passing in an `int`, but you're trying to get all kinds of other information to pass to the database. What does your stored procedure take as parameters, and where do you expect to get them from in your code?

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question to provide more context. Do you understand why you're getting this error? Do you understand that your method receives one integer, but you're trying to send five pieces of information to your stored procedure? Where do you expect to get the rest of the information from?

Comment: load Employee by given id and use it in your parameters

Comment: The signature of the stored procedure is key to understanding the intent. I suspect based on the name, p_GetLeaveRecord, that it accepts perhaps a single PARAMETER (an employee ID) and RETURNS the LeaveType, DateFrom as columns in the result set.  If so, you have ONE parameter and the rest of it is handled by the DataAdapter.Fill which will "pull" the result set into the DataSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `empID` as an `int` type parameter and later you are using it as a type in your parameters. For example.

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", empID.LeaveType);
```

I believe you have to pass your object probably of `EmployeeLeave` type in your method

```
GetLeaveRecord(int empID)
```

Or you may get your object based on the `ID` in your method and then use that in your parameters

Comment: So how to correct
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", empID.LeaveType);

Comment: @AmmarAsjad, what is the object that has `LeaveType` and other properties ? you need to pass that as an argument, not the int, Or you may get the object in the method against the ID and then use that in your parameters

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as intended. Did the code mean to lookup the employee details given the employee ID (empID)? Did you mean to pass in an Employee object instead? Are you missing a reference to a namespace that includes the extension methods to the int type?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the signature of your method

```
public DataSet GetLeaveRecord(int empID)
```

Please change it to

```
public DataSet GetLeaveRecord(Employee emp)
```

Pass entire employee object to this method

Comment: Int empId is coming from other class so i cant edit it to

public DataSet GetLeaveRecord(Employee emp)

Comment: Then retrieve emp object using empId, as you are using rest of the employee class properties

Answer (score 0):

Your method take a int as argument.

```
public DataSet GetLeaveRecord(int empID)
```

Later you try to use this as a type by doing

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", empID.LeaveType);
```

Are you sure about the argument should be a int and not a Employee or some object simulare that has these properties? LeaveType,EmployeeId...

Something like this?

```
public DataSet GetLeaveRecord(Employee emp)
```

Comment: @AmmarAsjad: Why? What do you expect it to do? You haven't provided *nearly* enough information about what you're trying to do, or what your stored procedure requires.